# Show bootstrap navbar after scroll past initial screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have an initial screen with a signup form and I want a navbar with a signup link to only appear after scrolling past the signup form. Is there a way to do this with jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this jquery to add the class 'snap' to a navigation bar when you scrolled past the top of the container (#container) containing the nav bar.
In this case, my 'snap' class gives my navigation a fixed position (relative to the body) so it'll stick to the top of the screen.

If you use this code, you can change #container for the id of the block that comes after your sign up form.
What I would do next is hide your navbar *maybe {top:-200px;}?* by default and then add a class to it ('snap' - or whatever is semantically meaningful for you) to make it appear *{top:0;}*.

```
$(window).scroll(function(scroll) {
    var navStart = $('#container').offset().top;

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > navStart) {
      $('nav').addClass('snap');
    } else {
      $('nav').removeClass('snap');  
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, but now the navbar still shows when I first reload the page, then disappears when I scroll a little.

Comment: Does your navbar have properties set to hide it by default?
If the simple solution (of updating the CSS) doesn't work for you, you could also add a line to your document.ready function to update the CSS properties on the navbar on load. If you're really stuck, I can take a look if you paste a link.

Comment: I have this in my css: body.homepage #navigation-top {display: none !important;}

Comment: `display:none` probably isn't the best approach, because (as far as I know) you can't animate/transition from nothing to something in the same way that you can animate from `opacity:0` to `opacity:1` or from `top:-200px` to `top:0px`. _I'd recommend using the web inspector on chrome to figure out exactly what's overwriting your display property_. If your `!important` is being ignored, there's a good chance you inlined some css and forgot about it or that your javascript is triggering prematurely.

Comment: I figured it out. I had my navbar starting with snap on so I just removed the snap div from the top of the navbar. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scrollTop function and an if statement to check against a variable such as the element height or position from the top.

https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();        

    if (scroll > x) {

    }
});
```